# oracle equivalent of hive collect_set function

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

What is the oracle equivalent of below hive query?

```
select appn_id,collect_set(CONCAT(upper(TRIM(dcsn_type_nm)),':',upper(TRIM(dcsn_outcm_nm))))
 FROM  <left join between few tables>
 group by appn_id
```

EDIT:

Updated based on Gordon's answer -

```
select appn_id,listagg(upper(trim(dcsn_type_nm)) || ':' || upper(trim(dcsn_outcm_nm))) within group (order by null) set_type_outcm_nm
 FROM  <left join between few tables>
 group by appn_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way this is being used, the equivalent is `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(upper(trim(dcsn_type_nm)) || ':' || upper(trim(dcsn_outcm_nm))) with group (order by null)
```

`listagg()` is an aggregation function, so it combine data from multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the query based on your answer. Can you please help verify it?

Comment: @PunterVicky . . . I think `listagg()` is probably the right solution.

Comment: Sorry , copied the wrong query. I corrected it now. Thanks for your help!